# RP-SMA and SMA conversion

Tags: rf, wireless

Firstly apologies for any stupidity here.

I am needing to purchase two 9dbi antennas for use with a router. I found someone online, bought them, then started noticing SMA and RP-SMA. Unbelievably I simply paid no attention before and long story short I bought the wrong thing.

In my brief reading I can see the differences between the connections, which is confusing to say the least and I see that RP means reverse polarity. I have also come across some converters for RP-SMA female to SMA male coax.

Presumably these will be sufficient for my purpose? Will there be any issues, loss. Am I better off purchasing another set of antennas with the correct connectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue with the adapters could be a mechanical one.  They are usually pretty short, so if you don't have good access to the connector it might be difficult to screw it in.  Also, you could run in to an issue where the antenna is screwed on to the adapter and then the adapter gets loose, but you can't unscrew the antenna because the adapter rotates and you can't access the adapter to either tighten it or loosen it.  So if you can access the connector easily even with the antenna installed, the adapter is probably a good option since you already bought the antennas.  Otherwise, it might be a better idea to buy the correct antennas.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. I think in this circumstance I will simply get the right tool for the job and buy the new antennas. One less layer of potential problem. Many thanks for taking the time to answer, much appreciated.